# Children are not being stored

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm making a little project with Hibernate and I have come to an issue that I couldn't find a solution:

I have a table call Solicitud(the "father") which is compose of several records of a another table DetalleSolicitud(the children), you can recall the  previous "model" like a bill and its sales details.

Well the thing when I try to save the "father", hibernate doesn't save its sons.

Seeing the sql statements that are generated by hibernate I noticed that the column that linked  the child with it father wasn't being stored:

```
Hibernate: insert into SOLICITUD (ESTADO, TIPOSOLICITUD, IDUSUARIO,  IDSOLICITUD) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into DETALLESOLICITUD (IDLAB, IDDIA, IDBLOQUE, IDDETALLE) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TOO"."DETALLESOLICITUD"."IDSOLICITUD")
```

as you can see the IDSOLICITUD column isn't a part of the sql statement for adding a new record to DETALLESOLICITUD being this one the column that links father and son. I don´t know why this happens because I thought my mapping files were the wrong ones, but they seem to be ok:

solicitud.hbm.xml

```
<class name="Solicitud" table="SOLICITUD">
    <id name="id" column="IDSOLICITUD">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SOLICITUD_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="estado" column="ESTADO"/>
    <property name="tipo" column="TIPOSOLICITUD"/>
    <many-to-one name="usuario_solicitante" class="Usuario">
        <column name="IDUSUARIO" not-null="true"></column>
    </many-to-one>
    <set name="detallesSolicitud" cascade="save-update" table="DETALLESOLICITUD">
        <key>
            <column name="IDSOLICITUD" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="DetalleSolicitud" />
    </set>
... Lots of other attributes...
```

detallesolicitud.hbm.xml

```
<class name="DetalleSolicitud" table="DETALLESOLICITUD">
    <id name="id" column="IDDETALLE">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">DETALLESOLICITUD_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
... Lots of other attributes ...
        </class>
```

So, if somebody can help me out,I would really appreciate it

Comment: Try to remove not-null="true" from <column name="IDSOLICITUD" not-null="true"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,I finally found out how to fix the problem: It seems I got bad references of one-to-many mapping tag.

The problem was the property

```
table="DETALLESOLICITUD"
```

in the line

```
<set name="detallesSolicitud" cascade="save-update" table="DETALLESOLICITUD">
```

Removing it, it's enough to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

There could be two ways -

one to remove not-null from solicitud.hbm.xml

```
 <set name="detallesSolicitud" cascade="save-update" table="DETALLESOLICITUD">
    <key>
        <column name="IDSOLICITUD"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="DetalleSolicitud" />
</set>
```

and other one I believe

you should save the father and flush the session and then save the child as then it will have not have null value of "TOO"."DETALLESOLICITUD"."IDSOLICITUD" from father.

Also make sure the sequence "SOLICITUD_SEQ" is already present in database.

Hope this helps. Thanks